Trying to figure out this error on React regarding Module Not found: Error
I'm new to react and following a tutorial and just initially wanting to display my webpage on my browser. I use the npm run start command and it does display the webpage on my browser but gives me this error:
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/bhaviksinghal/Documents/React Projects/Tutorial #2/dojo-blog/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '/Users/bhaviksinghal/Documents/React Projects/Tutorial #2/dojo-blog'
ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/bhaviksinghal/Documents/React Projects/Tutorial #2/dojo-blog/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '/Users/bhaviksinghal/Documents/React Projects/Tutorial #2/dojo-blog'
Could someone help me on how to debug this?
I tried looking at the index.js?... and it was like this:

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@bhaviks, can you share scripts on package.json  and  terminal you are trying to running the start command?

Can you delete your node-modules and try npm installl then run
